# Is there a way to swipe down instead of up to launch Mission Control?

Tags: macos, magic-trackpad, multi-touch, mission-control

To me it feels more natural to "pull" down the Desktop down to access Mission Control however System Preferences for the Magic Trackpad only allow for swiping up to access Mission Control.

Is there a hidden terminal preference or app that would enable swipe down to activate Mission Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) lets you assign arbitrary tap/swipe/click gestures to arbitrary commands.

It supports Lion.

Comment: Looks like the developer of BetterTouchTool has been aggressive to update it for Lion. I got it work however you have to have the latest version and disable three finger swipe up and down in the System Preferences for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

No way I can find without a third party-app, anyway.  I tried changing the function that is mapped by default to three-fingers-down (App Expose) to see if it would 'free it up' for mission control, but no dice.

I'm finding a lot of things like that (reversed scrolling!!!) less comfortable/intuitive, but trying where I can to just get used to them, as I expect they'll feel just as good eventually, and if so, will become standard practice all over the place.   (Yes, I know that "get used it" isn't what you asked for, but on this one, I don't think you can default to the old method you used for expose.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scrolling by going to preferences and track pad then unselect natural scroll

Comment: does this also affect the Mission Control swipe? Should be only for scrolling, no?